# Nested for loop sum of integers

Tags: java, java-io

```
public class NestedCountLoop
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; sum < 5050; i++) {
    sum = sum + i;
    System.out.println(sum);
    }
   } 
}
```

So I have a little homework assignment for my intro programming class to use a nested loop to accept positive integer input and add all of the integers within the interval from 1 to that input. My mind is playing games with me and I'm having trouble getting going. I know I need a scanner and whatnot, and it has to print every result from 1 to n such as "The sum of 1 to 100 is 5050." Any advice is helpful

Comment: So find a usage of scanner and try a simple input.

Comment: *I know I need a scanner and whatnot* good that you know what to use! Now do some more research about the usage of `Scanner` e.g. the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Comment: I can live with no downvotes, but why is it being upvoted?

Comment: @DaveNewton same thought...

Comment: @DaveNewton I didn't realize only map-reducing parallel sorting algorithms in O(1) time were the only kinds of questions you should upvote. That being said, why did you take the time to point this out?

Comment: @JustinC ... I know you're trying to be funny, and I appreciate the effort. Questions need to be *good* questions, regardless of their complexity. This isn't a good, there are a few reasons why, and these reasons are documented. Probably the same reason you took the time to be sarcastic and miss the point.

Comment: Did the answers help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Information on scanner at from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = o; i < 100; i++){
    int upperLimit = sc.nextInt();
    for (int w = 0; w < upperLimit; w++){
        sum = sum + i;
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured out to get the result that I wanted, but I just don't know how to make it a nested loop as requested. We have to have a second loop that loops 100 times

Comment: Can you be more specific about what the second loop is supposed to do?

Comment: Since I have a program that computes sum of 1 to n, I need to embed that into a second loop that loops 100 times, with the outside loop controlling the number of times it loops. The directions are pretty vague I suppose so I'm sorry if I can't explain well enough

Comment: I edited my response to reflect at least something of what you said.  The outside loop uses the scanner that I had before, and everytime it loops, you enter a new integer, the scanner gets it and uses that as the upper bound for the sum for-loop.  Hopefully that at least puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks man that actually got me to what I needed pretty much. I appreciate it

Comment: Don't forget to accept/upvote answers and questions as they help you.  Not just mine, but in general.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class NestedCountLoop
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
   {
    int to = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; sum < to; i++) {
       sum = sum + i;
       System.out.println(sum);
    }
   } 
}
```

How about this one? It takes an input from the command line (arg0), and adds every number to your number (not inclusive).

So you have to compile your java file with javac, then you can run:

```
javac NestedCountLoop.java
java NestedCountLoop.class 100
```

On the other hand, the a previous solution mentioned the javadoc for your scanner, if you really need to use it. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Enter your maximum number: ");

// get the input
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int max = input.nextInt();

int sum = 0;

// iterate through an array to sum up the numbers
for (int i = 1; i < max; i++) {
    sum = sum + i; // sum += i;
}

// print out the sum after you counted everything
System.out.println(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class sumoftenIntegerInput {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new  Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=1; i<=10; i++){
            System.out.println("Enter integer input " + i + ":");
            int a = input.nextInt();
            sum = sum + a ;

        }
        System.out.println("Total is:" + sum );
    }
}
```